# Gmail Mail Api Working in Api explorer but not in code c#

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I am using Gmail Api to get all the unread message in inbox , do some operations on it and then mark the mail as READ.

However when i do any of the below:

```
  var markAsReadRequest = new ModifyThreadRequest { RemoveLabelIds = new[] { "UNREAD" } };
  service.Users.Threads.Modify(markAsReadRequest, "xxx@gmail.com", email.ThreadId)
                                                                        .Execute();

  var markemail=new ModifyMessageRequest { RemoveLabelIds = new[] { "UNREAD" } };
  service.Users.Messages.Modify(markemail, "xxx@gmail.com", email.Id)
                                                                     .Execute();
```

I am getting Error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
```

Insufficient Permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

The thing is i open Api explorer and run the same request  and it works fine.
So not sure what am i doing wrong here.

```
gmail.users.threads.modify:

Modifies the labels applied to the thread. This applies to all messages in the thread.
```

This works and marks the email as UNREAD.

Comment: Please show us what **is** working from the API Explorer so we can compare the two.

Comment: @mjwills : gmail.users.threads.modify Modifies the labels applied to the thread. This applies to all messages in the thread.  This works and i confirm it by looking at the inbox and message is now read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue had to add this on top:

```
  static string[] Scopes = { mailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,GmailService.Scope.GmailModify };
```

Comment: how/where did you find the answer?

Comment: I looked at the code: this was already there "static string[] Scopes = { mailService.Scope.GmailReadonly" so  i assumed i have to add here.